# How to generate a html file from a markdown inputfile through command line argument

Tags: python, python-3.x, markdown, command-line-arguments, argparse

From the below part of a code I would like to generate an output in `.html` format from a given `.md` file through command line arguments

```
#main.py

import os, argparse,
import configparser, webbrowser

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser() 

parser.add_argument('--display', dest='display',action='store_true', help='displays the md file',default=None)
parser.add_argument('--inputmarkdown',type=argparse.FileType("r"),help='Provide the markdown file location')
parser.add_argument('--outputmarkdown', type = str, default = "./Output",help='Provide the output display file location')

args = parser.parse_args()

if args.display:
            subprocess.run(["pandoc", "--toc", "--standalone","--mathjax", "-t", "html", "--simple_tables", "args.inputmarkdown", "-o", "args.outputmarkdown", "--metadata", "pagetitle=test display"])
            url = "file://(args.outputmarkdown)"
            webbrowser.open(url,new=1,autoraise=True)
```

Using the below command line arguments

```
python3 main.py --display --inputmarkdown file/path/firsttest.md --outputmarkdown /file/path/test/firsttest.html
```

The above doesn't perform the task and I just have the webbrowser open with file:///
Can someone suggest where the issue is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is probably with the url string.  You are not formatting it.  And the variables in the subprocess call are quoted.

Try This

```
import os, argparse,
import webbrowser

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser() 

parser.add_argument('--display', dest='display', action='store_true', help='displays the md file', default=None)
parser.add_argument('--inputmarkdown', help='Provide the markdown file location')
parser.add_argument('--outputmarkdown', default="./Output", help='Provide the output display file location')
parser.add_argument('--pagetitle', dest='pagetitle', default='test display')

args = parser.parse_args()

if args.display:
    subprocess.run(["pandoc", "--toc", "--standalone", "--mathjax", "-t", "html", "--simple_tables", args.inputmarkdown, "-o", args.outputmarkdown, "--metadata", f"pagetitle={args.pagetitle}"])
    url = f"file://{args.outputmarkdown}"
    webbrowser.open(url,new=1,autoraise=True)
```

Comment: I dont think `args.inputmarkdown` works as I get `TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not _io.TextIOWrapper`

Comment: Still doenst work as it just displays .md file content in console rather than as a html file

Comment: its basically the same script as I have posted in my question, without the quotation marks for `args.inputmarkdown` which doesnt seem to work

Comment: @newstudent I also took out the argument in the `add_argument `   that gives `args.inputmarkdown` as `type=argparse.FileType`.   If it still isn't working what is the error message this time?

Comment: @yes, it did. I hadn't noticed the `type=file` omission. Thanks

Comment: can you suggest how to use `pagetitle=test display` with an additional argument ?something like `"pagetitle = args.pagetitle"`

Comment: @newstudent  See updated answer.  you will need to wrap the argument in quotes if you plan to use spaces though.  so the command would look like `prog --inputmarkdow ./path1 --outputmarkdow ./path2 --pagetitle "test display"`